# find and create hard link with regex in different path

Tags: regex, sed, find, ln

The below script finds a file, then creates a hard link in a destination path.

```
find /path/to/files -name "example" -exec ln {} /path/to/destination/ \;
```

I would like to create the link using the following

```
'y/./ /; s/[()]//g; s/^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+).*\s([a-z0-9]+)$/\1(\2).\3/;'
```

I've been trying to do this for a couple hours now. But with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Might be simpler to just throw those lines in a perl file and run that in your `find`.  You'll struggle running this on the command line in the `-exec` with the many layers of escaping you'll need.

Comment: I figured it out. Check out my answer, and let me know what you think? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I up-voted your answer, because it was very good information. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
new_movie_name=$(find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -size +500M \! -iname "*sample*" \! -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*e[0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" \( -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" \) -exec basename {} \;)

new_movie_directory=$(find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -size +500M \! -iname "*sample*" \! -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*e[0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" \! -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" \( -iname "*19[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*20[0-9][0-9]*" \) -exec dirname {} \;)

plex_movie_directory="/hdd_bottom-left/plex/movie"

ln "$new_movie_directory/$new_movie_name" "$(echo "$plex_movie_directory/$new_movie_name" | sed -r 'y/./ /; s/[()]//g; s/^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+).*\s([a-z0-9]+)$/\1(\2).\3/;')"
```